# How to save the hashtag value and restore on pageload?

Tags: variables, cookies, twitter-bootstrap, hashtag

I'm trying to figure out how to save and then restore the hashtag value in a url.  I'm doing it this way so the tab selected is persistent on the page's reload.  I'm using bootstrap atm and the code for the tabs is

```
  <div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">  
    <li class="active"><a href="#na" data-toggle="tab">North America</a></li>
    <li><a href="#euw" data-toggle="tab">Europe West</a></li>
    <li><a href="#eune" data-toggle="tab">Europe Nordic & East</a></li>
    <li><a href="#br" data-toggle="tab">Brazil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#kr" data-toggle="tab">Korea</a></li>
    </ul>
...(other stuff here that doesn't really matter)
```

Any help with this would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript cookies.

1. Add an onclick event for each  tag.  In that event, save a cookie with the name of the div.
2. Upon page load, check to see whether that cookie exists.  If it does, then simulate a click (using jQuery's .click() function, for example) on the div with that id.